# VBA Shape Objects

Tags: vba, ms-word

I pulled this code right of the internet. For some reason I'm getting a 'type mismatch' error on the `For Each objShape In reportDoc.Shapes` line. Maybe the reason is very very obvious, but I have no idea why.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub UseTextBox()

Dim objShape As Shape
Dim reportDoc As Object

Set reportDoc = ActiveDocument
MsgBox reportDoc

For Each objShape In reportDoc.Shapes
If objShape.Type = msoTextBox Then
    MsgBox TextFrame.TextRange
End If
Next objShape

End Sub
```

Comment: Which app version of VBA? Word?  The error is saying that reportDoc.Shapes is a not a collection of Shape - or not one that can be enumerated like this.

Comment: Looks like word vba -- maybe you should add that tag. The vba looks fine, so the problem is likely a misunderstanding of the word object model. You could  try declaring objShape as variant and displaying the result of typename(objShape) in the loop. The result might tell you what you need to declare objShape as. Maybe also display reportDoc.Shapes.Count and see wht you get. If it is 0 then it probably isn't the collection you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code. I got no 'type mismatch' error but a compile error on the line:

```
MsgBox TextFrame.TextRange
```

that should be

```
MsgBox objShape.TextFrame.TextRange
```